# Make second table header is fixed

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a two table where the second table is scrollable horizontally.

I want to make the header of this table is fixed.

Please refer [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/11/)

Here the headers of the  second table which is inside  `<div class="table2">` i want to make fixed.

How can I do it in simple way?

Comment: if i go down the header must not scroll down.. it is fixed.. want freeze the headers

Comment: I dont think that is possible with tables

Comment: I don't think you can make JUST the header of JUST the first column fixed. All I can think of is making the entire first column fixed(which is possible, I believe), not just the first column's header.

Comment: @s0d4pop - I tried doing that, using position fixed on the tr - didnt work. As I said, I am rather positive this is not possible with tables - if he was using divs, perhaps. :)

Comment: I did it, however its not that pretty: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/15/

Comment: @Jeff-Well, that's technically what he mentioned in his previous comment; the header of the first column doesn't move when you scroll down.

Comment: @s0d4pop "want freeze the headers" sounds to me like he wishes to make them stay when he scrolls down, cause in his example, they scroll like any other element. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/16/

As you see, its not that pretty - overlapping the first table cell, but this is what you asked.

EDIT: made the table2 header fixed.

Edit2: You should go with the jQuery plugin Telemako suggested.